# Resetting and Appending to Client Secrets on Service Principals in Azure Active Directory using Azure CLI does not reflect in the Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration

This is either a bug or there is a different place where I can access these records. Here is the scenario:

**I create a new app registration using the CLI:**

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name sp-name --role Contributor --years 2 --scope /subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx -o json
```

I can now see this app registration along with the secret reflected in the Azure portal. Testing access with the provided credentials work as expected.

**Here is where things get strange...**

I append a new Client Secret to this Service Principal by using the --append flag and give it a custom display name along with a different expiration time:

```
az ad sp credential reset --id xxx-xxx-xxx --end-date 2023-12-31 --display-name test-name --append
```

I get back the record for this new Client Secret along with the password to use. I test access using this password and it works. So it does exist. I go to the **Azure Portal > Active Directory > App Registrations > sp-name > Certificates & Secrets > Client Secrets** and all I see is the original Client Secret created with the display name of **rbac**.

Thinking there may be a caching issue I waited over 12 hours and I still do not see this new Client Secret anywhere on this SP. But I can use it and it works!

I also tried to reset the existing Client Secret (without the append flag) by calling:

```
az ad sp credential reset --id xxx-xxx-xxx --end-date 2023-12-31 --display-name rbac
```

And I get back a new password that works. But in the portal it still shows the password hint for the old password and the expiration data has not updated! Again I gave it 12+ hours and still no update.

What is also strange is **BOTH** the original and the new password WORK! What if I needed to do a reset due to a leak?

I have done this a number of times with the exact same results. Tried resetting existing Client Secrets as well as appending new ones. In both cases the data in the portal never reflects the new or updated info for Client Secrets created via the CLI.

It does not make sense that there would be no way to have a record of these secrets in the portal. Especially when we may need to find them years down the line. Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is the case?

I may also submit this as a bug. Will update if I hear back from that pursuit.

**UPDATED**

Using the CLI I can get back the correct info:

```
az ad sp credential list --id xxx-xxx-xxx
```

The new as well as the reset Client Secrets are both there and they reflect the correct password hints as well as expirations. So perhaps this is a portal bug.

But this still does not explain why the original password still works over 12 hours later. That one is shown in the portal but not in the CLI.

**UPDATE 2**

I filed feedback/reports for both the Azure Portal (for the UI not refreshing) as well as with AAD (For the ability to use old passwords after being reset).

Here are the links to both of these submissions. I could not find a proper bug reporting system so looks like these are more like "feature requests". If anyone can upvote these and/or provide additional comments maybe we can get some eyes on this from Microsoft:

[Azure Portal Bug](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/46deec37-b65a-ed11-a81b-000d3ae5ae95)

[Active Directory Request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/31a30658-f05a-ed11-a81b-000d3ae49307)

If anyone has a better place to post these let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating service principal secrets. What Azure Portal displays are application secrets. They're the same type of object and serve the same purpose but are stored in different places. The application is mostly a data model while the service principal is the object that gets authenticated and authorized. The latter represents the application in any given tenant.

If you want to update Azure AD application secrets, you can use the [AzureAD PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) or the [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) or one of [its SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview).

Comment: Thanks. Odd that there is no visual representation of an SP secret in the portal, but at least it is known and by design. Still curious why a reset password still works. That is a bit of a security flaw especially if the key was reset due to a leak.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the `az ad sp` command is for managing the service principal which is tied to a single tenant and the credentials are only visible via CLI or Graph API. The enterprise application credentials are potentially multi-tenant and visible in the portal as the client secrets. So make service principal client secrets that are visible in the portal UI you need to use `az ad app`.

```
az ad app credential reset --id ${CLIENT_ID}
az ad app credential list --id ${CLIENT_ID}
```

These are visible in **Azure Portal > Entra ID (Active Directory) > App Registrations > sp-name > Certificates & Secrets > Client Secrets**

Also, the commands appear to be linked in a way that's not logical. Note that both the application and service principal have the same `APPLICATION_ID`.

```
export APPLICATION_ID=uuid-here
export SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_OBJECT_ID=uuid-here
export ENTERPRISE_APPLICATION_OBJECT_ID=uuid-here
```

Both `credential list` commands work with `APPLICATION_ID` but give separate sets of results.

```
az ad app credential list --id $APPLICATION_ID
az ad sp credential list --id $APPLICATION_ID
```

These commands only work with these exact variables and also give separate sets of results, but the same results as if using `APPLICATION_ID`.

```
az ad app credential list --id $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_OBJECT_ID
az ad sp credential list --id $ENTERPRISE_APPLICATION_OBJECT_ID
```